# what i need is to get nationality ,month and count of month and for each nationality

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    subnationality, 
    CONVERT(varchar(3), SubDate) as months,
    COUNT(CONVERT(varchar(3), SubDate)) 
FROM
    xxx
WHERE
    CONVERT(varchar(3), SubDate) IN (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(3), SubDate) AS months  
                                     FROM xxx
                                     WHERE DATEPART(yyyy, SubDate) = 2017
                                     GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(3), SubDate))
```

Comment: Please add your table definitions as text, and describe what you have tried along with the result set you want. Example data is always helpful.

Comment: Actually what you need is a question. You have a vague description of the requirements and a query with no formatting at all. We can help but we can't do it for you.

Comment: Your outer query is missing a group by, but that means you want to remove the distinct.

Comment: Probably change your `COUNT()` over to a window function `COUNT(CONVERT(varchar(3), SubDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY subnationality) as count_of_months`